# How can I manually use TeamCity's bundled svnkit-cli?

Tags: svn, teamcity, svnkit

I can't install SVN on this box, but we have a TeamCity build agent configured which has svnkit bundled, including svnkit-cli.  Is it possible to invoke the cli programmatically, not through TeamCity?

Ideally in a one-liner bash command, something like...

```
$ java -classpath ".;/teamcity/plugins/svnAgent/lib/*" SVN --version
```

**I can't figure out the syntax to use the bundled svnkit-cli.  Is it possible?**

FYI:

```
$ ls /teamcity/plugins/svnAgent/lib/ | grep svn
svnPlugin.jar
svnkit-1.7.9.jar
svnkit-cli-1.7.9.jar
svnkit-javahl16-1.7.9.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked it out by studying the svnkit with ant [documentation](http://svnkit.com/kb/user-guide-ant.html%20asd).

```
java -cp ".:%teamcity.agent.home.dir%/plugins/svnAgent/lib/*" org.tmatesoft.svn.cli.SVN --version
```

Comment: fwiw, on a windows 2012 server, dropping the .: in classpath worked for us, i.e. _java -cp "%teamcity.agent.home.dir%/plugins/svnAgent/lib/*" org.tmatesoft.svn.cli.SVN --version_